# Process behind how system will take the particular path from environmental variables (At the time of using java commands)

Tags: java, path, environment-variables

At the time of compiling or using the java commands (ex: javac, java), how the system will take the particular Java Path set in an Environmental variable?

I know it will take and I know about environmental variables. I Just want to know how the system will take. Can any one explain the process behind it??

Answer (score 0):

`CLASSPATH` environment variable may be used to define a classpath instruction for `java` and `javac` (and other JDK tools). You could do the following on Unix-like systems (for example, Linux):

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/user/path/to/dir1:/home/user/path/to/dir2:/opt/other-dir
```

Then, when you execute `java` or `javac`, having that environment variable would have the effect of adding a `-classpath` key, for example

```
javac Test.java
```

will work in the same way as the following command would work without any environment variable defined:

```
javac -classpath /home/user/path/to/dir1:/home/user/path/to/dir2:/opt/other-dir Test.java
```

More information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

**How java reads this property from OS**

Source is available here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/bin/java.c

```
cpath = getenv("CLASSPATH");
```

They use `getenv()` function from C library: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getenv.htm

Comment: Hey, I know how to add and why to add. I just need to know the backend process that how the system gonna take the path. Any way to just know the process?

Comment: Please elaborate on what is that 'backend process' you are interested in. Do you need to know how that environment variable is read by javac from the OS? Or you need to know how javac scans classpath to find classes?

Comment: Hey Roman,
Thanks for your reply. Yes, I want to know how javac reads from OS.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need this (and I believe that I did not understand your question completely), but I've updated the answer with the details on *how* java takes `CLASSPATH` environment variable from OS.